# Why do I receive this message: "items collection must be empty before using itemssource" in a treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

I'm receiving this error: "items collection must be empty before using itemssource" in a treeview.
My XAML code just contains:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
</TreeView>
```

Groups is a class where contains only two properties: GroupID and GroupName. I'm sure that my collection has items, but I'm not sure what's the reason for thix exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs when you have items added to the `Items` collection and use the `ItemsSource`, e.g.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListBoxItem Content="A concrete item"/>
</ListBox>
```

You can of course create such a problem in code too. So make sure you did not add anything manually somewhere.

Comment: Oh that's right. Then, how can I create my data template binding to control properties? I said this because I'm receiving the same error

Comment: @OscarFimbres: You probably forgot to put the property tags around your template, i.e. `<TreeView.ItemTemplate>...</TreeView.ItemTemplate>`, if you omit the tags the template is added as item.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: Then it follows that you must have done so in XAML. Sometimes people forget the property wrappers and e.g. add a `DataTemplate` as item when it should be the `ListBox.ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it can't get its items from two places. You have to pick one. Do you want your items to come from a datasource, or from a manual list?

I would bet you have items inside the tree view like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <!-- An Item being defined in the treeview -->
</TreeView>
```

Or you have code that does something like this

```
myTreeView.Items.Add(item)
```

Only one source of items can exist. You have to pick one.

Comment: The question I asked wasn't a yes/no question, it was a multiple choice question. Clarified the answer.